# How to render multiple templates for a route in Router v2

Tags: ember.js

my index template has two outlets, one for header, another for content. the template rendered in the content changes depending on the content being viewed.

In the old router, this could be done by calling `connectOutlet` on different controllers who owned that template. I can't figure out how to do the same in the new router.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With my research, I came to this:
Say you have a router defined like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/').to('index');
});
```

ApplicationTemplate:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{outlet header}}
{{outlet}}
</script>
```

IndexTemplate:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
{{outlet dashboard}}
{{outlet spaces}}
</script>
```

Now, What we want is that when user goes to the index router, the page should:

- Render index into main outlet and header into header outlet of application template.
- render dashboard, spaces template into Index Template.

To achieve this, we write the following code in indexRoute

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
        //Render header into header outlet
        this.render('header',{
            outlet:'header'
        });
        //Render index into main outlet. If you comment out 
        //this line, the code below fails
        this.render('index');

        //by using into, we can render into the index template
        //Note: The controller is optional.if not specified,
        //ember picks up controller for the given template.
        this.render('dashboard',{
            outlet:'dashboard',
            into:'index',
            controller:this.controllerFor('somethingElse', App.TestModel.find())
        });
        //controller is SpacesController
        this.render('spaces',{
            outlet:'spaces',
            into:'index'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Fairly similar to my original answer huh?

Comment: My 1st thought was to ask you to just update your functions to conform with ember-latest, so that I can accept your answer.
However, want I really wanted was the this.render('index') and subsequent renders into it. Your code only renders into the application template. This, combined with correct way to assign `content` of controllers led me to write a new answer

Comment: Why do both templates have the name 'index', i.e. the `data-template-name` attribute value 'index'?

Comment: oops, my mistake. Corrected them.

Comment: Why does App.IndexRoute have to know about {{outlet header}}?

Comment: @adivis It's fine to borrow code from another poster's answer but you should acknowledge from the code came from.

Answer (score 11):

you can use the renderTemplates function in the router to render mulitple views to name outlets:

```
renderTemplates:function () {
   this.render('todos_list', {
       into:'todos', //template name
       outlet: 'todos', //named outlet
       controller: 'listController' //controller you want to use
   });
   this.render('todos_test', {
       into:'todos',
       outlet: 'test',
       controller: 'testController'
   });
},

setupControllers:function (controller, model) {
   this.controllerFor('list').set('content', listmodel.find());
   this.controllerFor('test').set('content', testmodel.find());
}
```

The setupControllerControllerFor function will allow you to assign what we set as 'context' in the previous router.

In your template, you would name outlets just as before:

```
{{outlet list}}
{{outlet test}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It seems that setupControllers and renderTemplates have been deprecated in ember-latest.

Comment: hmmm...are you sure? the new guides on the ember site advise them: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/

Comment: just got merged 5 hrs ago. [this one](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/6d771b7a9389fff826b8f2e500721da6a7ce2fc0) and [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2468b42f801dc192a6e762293f3590d25274dfd0). But will try your code with the new functions.

Comment: ah! Let me know if you need anymore help.